# Apply a function across multiple Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, list, multiple-columns, apply

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
 df=   SlNo    A    B   C      D1   D2  D3

        1      1     2   3     21   32   32
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33 
        1      1     2   3     21   32   32
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33 
        1      1     2   3     21   32   32
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33 
        1      1     2   3     21   32   32
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33
```

Here D1, D2, D3 represent dependent variables and A, B,C the causal variables. The following is the output expected

```
        SlNo    A    B   C      D1   D2  D3   RD1  RD2  RD3

        1      1     2   3     21   32   32    25   23   21
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33    23   24   27
        1      1     2   3     21   32   32    23   21   26
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33    25   27   21
        1      1     2   3     21   32   32    24   22   21
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33    24   23   26
        1      1     2   3     21   32   32    25   26   28
        2      2     1   3     21   22   33    21   25   26
```

RD1, RD2, RD3 refer to three columns generated by randomforest algorithm.

```
     from sklearn.ensmeble import RandomForestClassifier
       Y=df[D1]
       X=df[A, B,C]
       clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
       clf.fit(X, Y)
       df[RD1]=clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Since I have many columns, is it possible to apply this function across multiple 
 columns- D1, D2, D3 simultaneously and generate columnns RD1, RD2, RD3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a for loop on a list of dependent variables.

```
from sklearn.ensmeble import RandomForestClassifier

dep_var_list - ['D1', 'D2', 'D3']

for i in dep_var_list:
    rd = 'R' + i
    Y=df[i]
    X=df[A, B,C]
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
    clf.fit(X, Y)
    df[rd]=clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that applies this to a single row and then pass that function to:

[pandas.DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)